# Почему оператор быстрее функции?

Tags: c++, c

> `new` is faster than `malloc()` because an operator is always faster than a function.

[Источник](https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-tutorial/difference-between-new-and-malloc.aspx)

Comment: Вы вообще прочитали то что идет после `new is faster than malloc()`?

Comment: Качество информации в источнике не является очевидно высоким.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591196/are-calloc-malloc-faster-than-operator-new-in-c

Comment: malloc всегда быстрее, чем new потому что мы можем выделить сколько нужно памяти один раз, а не для каждого объекта по отдельности. Источник: Я. Тот же источник сообщает, что при прочих равных компилятор способен собрать идентичный код для обеих операций.

Comment: Вы процитировали бессмыслицу из низкокачественного источника. Основанный на этой бессмыслице вопрос  и сам бессмыслен.

Comment: этот сайт богат непроверенными ляпами. Причем иногда работающими, но с неправильным объяснением. Например сравнение без ветвления.. В зависимости от контекста и реализации (компилятора), стандартный new МОЖЕТ быть быстре чем malloc(), особенно если это placement new. Однако ничто этого не гарантирует, на большинстве "больших" платформ, WIndows, Linux он не медлленнее из-за того что оба проходят через ABI вызовы. В случае нетривиальных типов он заведомо медленнее (исполнение конструктора)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это полнейшная глупость, в топку такие статьи.

`new` обычно немного медленнее.

[Подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570552/why-are-new-delete-slower-than-malloc-free).

[Замеры времени](http://quick-bench.com/vtq7JqomvOg0Vqllcnap7PRVtg0).

Comment: по карйней в этом тулчейне new является оберткой вокруг функции, используемой в calloc. При инициализации значением new int() и calloc дают одно и то же время даже в бенчмарке.